# gtkmm manage/add vs smart pointers:

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, lifecycle, gtkmm

gtkmm provides lifetime management of widgets using this sort of construct:

```
Gtk::Widget* aWidget = Gtk::manage(new Widget()); 

Gtk::Widget containerWidget;

containerWidget.add(*aWidget);
```

This delegates lifetime management of aWidget to containerWidget. When containerWidget is cleaned up, it also cleans up aWidget - similar to Delphi's 'owner' concept.

We also have several types of smart pointers, particular the  C++ 11 smart pointers templates, which I use everywhere.

I find the manage/add syntax easier and cleaner to use, but it's not part of the C++ Standard, it's a gtkmm specific feature, which makes me think I should stick to std::shared_ptr, etc.

So I'm wondering what are the advantages/disadvantages of std smart pointers vs the gtkmm manage/add model (aside from cases where you need the reference after the owner container has been deleted, or when you have a top level widget that has no containing widget).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think it's practical to use `shared_ptr` for widgets if you don't need to keep a reference to that widget after you add it. You are better off having a managed widget  instead using `shared_ptr`.

The nice thing about the gtk::manage is that you can create the object on the heap and add it to the container and forget about it, and when that container is destroyed it will destroy the widget.

As a general rule I create my widgets managed if I don't need to reference them after I add them to a container, if I do need to reference them, I allocate a pointer.

Comment: +1 - "The nice thing about the gtk::manage..." Yes. Exactly as in my example. But "you are better off having that widget on the stack" - sometimes that doesn't quite work out so well. But I really like manage/add - probably will stick with it whenever possible.

Comment: I have had this question up for a week, back and forth on stackOverflow and programmers - you're the first one to answer anything! I think maybe people don't know that much about gtkmm -which is actually kickass. So much discussion about WxWidgets, Qt, GTK+ - but gtkmm on top of GTK+ beats them all IMO once you find your way around. Once I found the docs in Glade I was hooked.

Comment: I like Gtkmm a lot, I use it at work all the time, about the Widget on the stack, if you can create a share_ptr you can put the widget on the stack xD(since you need to put the smart pointer on the stack anyways), I guess tho if you want use polymorphism then you would need the object on the heap and a smart pointer would be useful. If you need the widget in several classes, then a share_ptr would be good. But as a general rule I do my widgets manage if I dont need to reference them after I add em, If i do need to reference them, I put them on the stack.

Comment: "But as a general rule ..." that seems to be about how it comes out. Put that stuff in your answer - I will accept it.

Comment: @Vector Yup, GTKmm beats its competitors by far IMO. All the powr and support/docs of GTK+ with none of the C boilerplate - and none of the ugly quasi-C++ of Qt, nor its penchant to spam pointers everywhere. My current project has no heap-allocated widgets except those the API only exposes via `RefPtr`. FLTK looked nice for a while until I realised how split it is between its two (or is that 1.5?) versions. wxWidgets uses GTK+ anyway on Linux, and it's full of `MACROS(ugh)`, so nah. GTKmm ftw! I'm excited to use it and see its continuing evolution alongside the language.

Comment: _My current project has no heap-allocated widgets except those the API only exposes via RefPtr_   I built GUI app  at home doing exactly that and became a convert: Allows you to build GUI apps in solid C++ and in the true spirit of RAII - just an awesome thing.